# Javascript functions by url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a script that does some calculations and returns a Google Maps direction drawn on a map with the API.

I will keep my question easy and use this example:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
function DoMath(){
  //random number 1-20 for example
  a = random(1,20);
  b = random(1,20); 
  c = a + b;
}
```

So now the function makes a sum with random numbers. I want it like this:

When the users types after the site url /5/14 that the JavaScript sets a to 5 and b to 14 and uses those numbers instead of randoms. I also want the script to use randoms when there is nothing given in url.

Questions:

- How do I read url?
- How do I set the var to the url value?
- How can I make it so you could give only `a` or `b` or both in the
  url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the

> document.location.pathname

This variable returns the url's pathname.

Example:

> /questions/23874345/javascript-functions-by-url

Now you need to split this with '/'

```
var args = document.location.pathname.split('/');
```

Now you can use the 'args' array. (Note: args[0] returns "")

```
var a = parseInt(args[1]);
var b = parseInt(args[2]);
```

If you want to make sure no extra data is entered in the url use:

```
if (args.length > DESIREDVARIABLES) alert('Too many data');
```

Something like that =)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using codeigniter as framework, how is it possible to read whats behind the first / if the framework routes to a 401 error?

Comment: Well, sorry but i don't know codeigniter, and this question is javascript related, but in PHP you can get the server name (the thing behind the first /) via this: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] this will return 'stackoverflow.com' or 'www.stackoverflow.com' in this case.

Comment: Is there a way to do it like this:
url.com?rest=1&cafe=2&query=London
how can i read that?

Comment: @Onovar - If your server is not equipped to leave the pathname alone, then you can put the arguments in the query string:  `/questions?arg1=5&arg2=14` and then parse those out of the URL.